# GA4 how to get ga:uniqueEvents and ga:uniquePageviews

Tags: google-analytics, metrics, google-analytics-4

In google analytics GA4, how can I obtain metrics equivalent to "ga:uniqueEvents" and "ga:uniquePageviews" from the old version Universal Analytics (UA)?